# P&T switch in with lightbox integration issue

Tags: channel-entries, templates, custom-fields

I'm sure i have selected the perfect title for this however, if someone can come up with a better title, feel free to edit.

Anyway, I am having a slight issue integrating a combination of functions using P&T switch. I am currently using the Jquery plugin [fancybox](http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/) for my gallery [Click here][2] when you click on the image it meant to open a pop window.

I am using P&T switch as the gallery will feature both images and videos, In the expression control panel have created variables that look like the following[image: click here] This will enable the user to select a video or image, The video will navigate to the template {'pop/video'} and the images will navigate to {'pop/video-pop'}.

In order for me to a achieve this i have attempted to apply the following code to my gallery, however it's not working

```
<div class="am-container" id="am-container">
        {exp:low_reorder:entries set="gallery_set" channel="gallery" disable="pagination|member_data|trackbacks"}
            <a class="various" href="{if video_switch == "image"}{path='pop/index/{url_title}'}{/if}{if video_switch == "video"}{path='pop/video-pop/{url_title}'}{/if}">
            <img onmouseover="removeFilter(this)" onmouseout="addFilter(this)" src="{g_image}" alt="{url_title}" class="filter"></a>
        {/exp:low_reorder:entries}
        </div>
```

Can someone please guide me in the right direction..?

Comment: If my answer below helped you, would you be so kind as to mark it as the correct answer (with the "check" to the left of it)? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked at your link and can't see from looking at the front-end what would be the issue. What always helps for me is adding "debug" info to my HTML. You could for example try this:

```
{exp:low_reorder:entries set='gallery'}
    <!-- {video_switch} -->
{/exp:low_reorder:entries}
```

To output the value of this field for your entries. If the output is what you expect it, you could test further like so:

```
{exp:low_reorder:entries set='gallery'}
    {if '{video_switch}' == 'image'}
        <!-- this must be an image -->
    {/if}
    {if '{video_switch}' == 'video'}
        <!-- this ought to be a video -->
    {/if}
{/exp:low_reorder:entries}
```

It might be a typo or something. If you need further assistance set up a page that has code along these lines and please share the code and the url.

Good luck!